# How do I pass Variables from my site to another site without leaving my site?

Tags: php

I would like to be able to send variables to another website without actually going to the website using php.

I am building an ecommerce website where the shipping warehouse is being outsourced. After the person checks out with their products, I would like to send some variables over to the shipper's website using $_GET['vars']. This is a completely different URL. The problem is, I don't want the person actually going to the shipper's webpage. I just want to ping that info over there.

Is is possible to send Variables via URL to another site without leaving yours?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. the simplest way:

```
 $contents = file_get_contents("http://example.com/some/page.php?var=abcd");
```

For more advanced features see [Curl](http://id2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: While this will work, doing this will cause your page to run rather sluggish, better to load it with ajax imo.

Comment: In this specific case, it seems that ajax would be my best solution. I am excited to try this solution first and see what the shipping department will except. Thanks everyone for their input. I'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing all the relevant order info within your database then using cron to trigger a script that will process the unprocessed, this way systematic checks can be made on orders before any request to your outsource site. Dont rely on your users browser to hit a curtain point in the order process to trigger the API call or trust them not to triple click or inject values before submitting.

And I advise to use curl todo your actual request as its faster. Something as simple as:

```
<?php 
function curl_do_api($url){
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are right and you should make your choice based on security you're looking for.

cURL will be more secure and you should use it if you do not want to pass some argument in query string. At the same time when you pass data using file_get_cotents("URL?data=value"); you will have limit of about 2k for data being passed.

On the other side cURL will be secure if you use it with https it's much more secure. With cURL you will also be able to post files and emulate form post.

Answer (score 0):

actually there is a more simpler way of solving this...using **ajax** 
include the jquery header first
 
refer here
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/